# String with URL-ENCODING

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ascii, url-encoding

Hello I have an string with URL-ENCODING , %3A , %2F ...

http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fimage%2Fflv%2F1%2F8%2Fa%2Fimage_18060.jpg%3Fe%3D13777194

I would like to replace the "special characters" http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp to ASCII characters , I am programing in Rails but i dont have idea from where i can start.  Do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much for your help!

---

hummm
in this way Can I use URI.unescape?

```
scraper = Scraper.define do
    array :items
    process "div.mozaique>div", :items  => Scraper.define {
      process "div.thumb>a", URI.unescape(:link) => "@href"
      result :link
    }
    result :items
  end




/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:331:in `unescape': undefined method `gsub' for :link:Symbol (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:649:in `unescape'
    from /Users/jcr/web/sss/app/controllers/cweb.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in main_web'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/scrapi-2.0.0/lib/scraper/base.rb:986:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/scrapi-2.0.0/lib/scraper/base.rb:986:in `define'
    from /Users/jcr/web/sss/app/controllers/cweb.rb:15:in `block in main_web'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/scrapi-2.0.0/lib/scraper/base.rb:986:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/scrapi-2.0.0/lib/scraper/base.rb:986:in `define'
    from /Users/jcr/web/sss/app/controllers/cweb.rb:13:in `main_web'
    from /Users/jcr/web/sss/app/controllers/cweb.rb:57:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`URI.unescape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-unescape):

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'uri'
=> true
irb(main):006:0> URI.unescape("http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fimage%2Fflv%2F1%2F8%2Fa%2Fimage_18060.jpg%3Fe%3D13777194")
=> "http://mydomain.com/image/flv/1/8/a/image_18060.jpg?e=13777194"
```